# Getting data out of tableadapters

Tags: c#, ms-access

I just can't understand this thing: I have an access DB I want to query using c#. I read there are this useful tableadapters that make most of the job for you.
Here is what I have done:

1. Added new data source to the project though the wizard
2. Added a table adapter via the toolbox. The table adapter has a query named GetData that I want to use to retrieve results.
3. I add these lines to the code to make my textbox show my first result

   ```
   Database_CeciDataSetTableAdapters.BaseTableAdapter tableadapter = new Database_CeciDataSetTableAdapters.BaseTableAdapter();
       textBox1.Text = tableadapter.GetData()[0].ToString();
   ```

Here is what I get in the textbox:

```
WordAddIn5.Database_CeciDataSet+BaseRow
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you receive a row. I've tried myself but - to get a field - try: `= tableadapter.GetData()[0][0].ToString();`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I needed to tell which part of the row I was looking for! Thank you!